# FileUpload via Session variable over certain size and get "Cannot access a closed file" error

Tags: asp.net

I created an empty ASP.NET app with 2 pages, Default.aspx and Action.aspx (please see below).  When running, I select a 200k .bmp file and click to save.  I then get a "Cannot access a closed file" error BUT ONLY when my source file is above 55k or so.  What gives?  thanks

### Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="attachmentFileUpload" Width="300px" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="saveButton_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Simple : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["AttachmentFileUpload"] = attachmentFileUpload;
            Response.Redirect("Action.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

### Action.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Action.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Action" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Action.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Action : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileUpload tempFileUpload = (FileUpload)Session["AttachmentFileUpload"];
            tempFileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\MyUpload.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't store controls in session.

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file is not kept inside the `FileUpload` control, the control only has a reference to the response stream where the actual data is.

The entire response stream is not read until it is needed, but if the uploaded file is small it will have been read into the buffer of the stream. When you do a redirect, the response stream will be closed, so anything that isn't already in the buffer will not be possible to read.

You have to save the uploaded file in the page where it arrives, you can't save the `FileUpload` control for later and reliably get the file from it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies.  My actual scenario is on a single page but there are also country/state/city dropdownlist boxes that do postbacks.

E.g. consider the user selecting a file to upload and then changing the state which does a postback to re-populate the city dropdownlist.  In that case, you'd lose the value of the FileUpload.  Just tough luch and they'd need to re-select?  thanks again.